# Верстка: мультивыбор

Tags: вёрстка

Нужны светлые головы, обремененные опытом web-программирования или хотя бы верстки.

Имеется несколько категорий, в каждой категории имеется несколько значений.

**Идея такая:** в каждой категории пользователь выбирает некоторые значения, а те, что не выбрал, динамически обрабатываются скриптом и внизу вываливается формочка для разъяснения причин, почему не было выбрано то или иное значение.

Имеется проблема с представлением, как это может/будет выглядеть, чтобы глаза не лопались, а сердце радовалось.

И да, совсем забыл. Работа будет на планшете.
Из-за немного корявого отображения на планшете отпал вариант с
http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/hlmri
и с http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index

Нужен совет, как лучше сделать эти элементы? Опыта мало в разработке.

У меня пока что идея одна - сделать для каждой категории обрамление и тупо накидать checkbox-ов.

Comment: Chosen? http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @олег-б, Сегодня попадал, но как-то не обратил должного внимания. Хорошая идея!
Единственный вопрос у меня закрался... как обработать выбранные значения?

Comment: Понял, как обработать, спасибо большое, Олег Б!

Answer (score 1):

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/